# Is this proof correct (Cartesian Products and Subsets)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove that if $A \times B$ is a subset of $A \times C$ then $B$ is a subset of $C$ given that $A$ is not empty. I've looked at this question on here and I'm aware it's been asked. My question is about a specific part of the proof.

I get to the point where I have $(x \in A \wedge y \in B) \to (y \in C)$. From here am I allowed to say that $B \subseteq C$? Am I missing some step to eliminate $x \in A$?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. It'd be good to see the rest of your proof, but the logic should begin with "Suppose $y \in B$", then for some $x \in A$ you consider $(x,y)$ as an element of $A \times B$, from which you find that $(x,y) \in A \times C$: in particular, $y \in C$. That's enough to show $B \subseteq C$. The important thing is getting to $y \in C$ from $y \in B$, even if you seem to take a detour along the way.